# Premake generated solution wont compile in Release but compiles in Debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, release, lnk2019, premake

I have a Project set up in [Premake](https://premake.github.io/) that consists of a `SharedLib` and a `ConsoleApp` that links to that `SharedLib`. Furthermore, the `SharedLib` links to the [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) binaries.
I successfully setup before:
- A premake Project that contains a `ConsoleApp` and a `SharedLib` it links to
- A premake Project that contains a `ConsoleApp` that links to the SFML binaries
But combining both just wont work out in the `release`build

Here is the output that MSVC 2012 produces:

```
2>  main.cpp
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(void)" (__imp_??0RenderWindow@sf@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow(void)" (__imp_??1RenderWindow@sf@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
2>..\..\.bin\Example\Release\Example.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The folder structure of my premake Project:

```
SFML_PROJECT
|-- .libraries
|   `-- SFML-2.3.2-Win32
|       |-- include
|       |-- lib
|       `-- bin
|-- example
|   `-- main.cpp
|-- include
|   |-- App.h
|   `-- Config.h
|-- src
|   `-- App.cpp
`-- premake5.lua
```

And my [`premake5.lua`](http://pastebin.com/4ZGimRRM) (I am sorry for the rather large file but If I would shorten it I might miss something important)

*To summarize my release config of the `ConsoleApp`*:
- I added the `SFML include`
- I link to the `SharedLib` Project that links to the SFML binaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added an empty constructor and destructor in `App.h`/`App.cpp` and it seems to work for now...

I would really appreciate if somebody could explain me why I need to define those if I use `App.h`/`App.cpp` as part of a `dll` but not if I use them directly as part of an `Executable`.